# How do different stresses change the meaning of the sentence "I don't know"

Tags: stress

If one says "I don't know" in 3 different ways, like, when they stress "I", "don't" and "know" respectively. How does the meaning of this sentence change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a stress on "I" in "I don't know," you're actually making a distinction between who you are talking about: "I" don't know! (not him, her, etc.)

When "don't" is stressed, it is meant to emphasize the negativity of the sentence: I "don't" know! (in contrast with "I know!").

And finally when you put a stress on the verb "know," you're emphasizing what you don't do: I don't "know"! (in contrast with, say, I don't "want" or I don't "like"!)

Comment: Put another way, emphasis on “I” is equivalent to “Don’t ask ME” or Search ME”.  It is non-committal as to whether anyone else knows.  “I DON’T know” needs context.  It could be a response to “I’m sure know what happened next”.  No, I DON’T (know).”.  I might have said  don’t know already and you insist I must know.  Then I stress the auxiliary.  3 depends on context.  You might declare I don’t know my children, so I say (incredulously, “I don’t KNOW them?”  Or it could be that you keep repeating the same question, till finally I say I don’t KNOW!” (exasperatedly).

Answer (score 2):

**I** don’t know. Someone else knows it. It’s true that somebody knows it, but I am not that person.

I **don’t** know. That’s not true at all. Somebody has accused me and I’m protesting my innocence.

I don’t **know**. I only can suggest a possibility. In some way, I hint that, but I don’t have exact knowledge.